# Relate gender distribution to age distribution in R

Tags: r, contingency

I'm trying to create a data.frame in which I´ve added the share of the different sexes of the age distribution proportionally to the age distribution.

I have the following two data.tables

```
 date time age confirmed deceased
   1: 2020-03-02    0  0s        32        0
   2: 2020-03-02    0 10s       169        0
   3: 2020-03-02    0 20s      1235        0
   4: 2020-03-02    0 30s       506        1
   5: 2020-03-02    0 40s       633        1
  ---                                       
1085: 2020-06-30    0 40s      1681        3
1086: 2020-06-30    0 50s      2286       15
1087: 2020-06-30    0 60s      1668       41
1088: 2020-06-30    0 70s       850       82
1089: 2020-06-30    0 80s       556      139


date time    sex confirmed deceased
  1: 2020-03-02    0   male      1591       13
  2: 2020-03-02    0 female      2621        9
  3: 2020-03-03    0   male      1810       16
  4: 2020-03-03    0 female      3002       12
  5: 2020-03-04    0   male      1996       20
 ---                                          
238: 2020-06-28    0 female      7265      131
239: 2020-06-29    0   male      5470      151
240: 2020-06-29    0 female      7287      131
241: 2020-06-30    0   male      5495      151
242: 2020-06-30    0 female      7305      131
```

Is it possible to infer the share of sexes on each age group?

In general, I want to control the effect third control variable (the age distribution) on the corona deceases. There´s a trend that the deceased rate of men is higher than of women. I would like to investigate the frequency distribution of the age groups between the ages to find maybe more explanation.

I'm thankful for any advice

Comment: Can you give a small sample of the data? Combine the two data frames and dput a few rows of data.

Comment: Ho can i share you this data? Otherwise, you can find it here: `https://www.kaggle.com/kimjihoo/coronavirusdataset` . I used the TimeGender and TmeAge data sets. I can´t merge the because TimeGender has two entries of one date due two two gender types and TimeAge has 9 entries of data.

Comment: Do you want to know the share of sexes in each category of ages? For the confirmed cases and deaths? You can group_by both age and sex and then count the cases for each combination of age and sex groups. What does age measure here? I see a lot of zeros and s at the end.

Comment: ```# for age data set: dplyr solution

df1 %>% 
group_by(age) %>% 
summarise(N = n(), tot_cases = sum(confirmed))
```
The same goes for the data set by gender. You need to combine the two data frames in order to find the shares by sex in each age group.

Comment: If you manage to merge the two data sets with a proper key, then this simple code can give you the confirmed cases by age-sex combination: aggregate(confirmed~age+sex, sum, data = df)

Comment: Do you know what I do wrong?

Comment: You do not need dplyr for that. Try this: `aggregate(confirmed~age, sum, data = TimeAge_dt)`

Comment: You are getting the error because you are passing a subset of the data frame rather than the name of the variable. Try this: `TimeGender_dt %>% group_by(age) %>% summarise(N = n(), tot_cases = sum(confirmed) )`

Comment: But i have two data tables. How can I provide " data=" with more than one source?

Comment: You cannot. You need to merge the two into one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a way to merge the two data sets in order to compute the shares by sex-age combinations. But it seems they cannot be merged as there are no common keys other than `date` which is not a unique identifier.

```r
age = read.csv("TimeAge.csv")
sex = read.csv("TimeGender.csv")

head(age)
       date time age confirmed deceased
1 2020-03-02    0  0s        32        0
2 2020-03-02    0 10s       169        0
3 2020-03-02    0 20s      1235        0
4 2020-03-02    0 30s       506        1
5 2020-03-02    0 40s       633        1
6 2020-03-02    0 50s       834        

head(sex)
        date time    sex confirmed deceased
1 2020-03-02    0   male      1591       13
2 2020-03-02    0 female      2621        9
3 2020-03-03    0   male      1810       16
4 2020-03-03    0 female      3002       12
5 2020-03-04    0   male      1996       20
6 2020-03-04    0 female      3332       12

aggregate(confirmed~age, sum, data = age)
  age confirmed
1  0s     16107
2 10s     68752
3 20s    345827
4 30s    137539
5 40s    168250
6 50s    230030
7 60s    158505
8 70s     82107
9 80s     54086

aggregate(confirmed~sex, sum, data = sex)
     sex confirmed
1 female    747467
2   male    513727
```